# Horizontal reduction operation on Array columns

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

An example of horizontal operation is [`pl.any_horizontal`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html) which can be apply across the `pl.Boolean` columns, i.e.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pl.Series(
            "a", 
            [False, False],
            dtype=pl.Boolean,
        ),
        "b": pl.Series(
            "b", 
            [True, False],
            dtype=pl.Boolean,
        ),
    }
)

df.with_columns(pl.any_horizontal("a", "b"))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ a     ┆ b     ┆ any   │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ true  ┆ true  │
│ false ┆ false ┆ false │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Is there a way to apply the same operation across columns containing `pl.Array` data types? That is

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pl.Series(
            "a", 
            [[False, False], [False, True]],
            dtype=pl.Array(width=2, inner=pl.Boolean),
        ),
        "b": pl.Series(
            "b", 
            [[True, False], [True, True]],
            dtype=pl.Array(width=2, inner=pl.Boolean),
        ),
    }
)

df.with_columns(pl.any_horizontal("a", "b"))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ a              ┆ b              ┆ any            ┆
│ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆
│ array[bool, 2] ┆ array[bool, 2] ┆ array[bool, 2] ┆
╞════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ [false, false] ┆ [true, false]  ┆ [true, false]  │
│ [false, true]  ┆ [true, true]   ┆ [true, true]   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
(This is the result I wanna get but an error is thrown)
```

In theory this should be a well-defined operation if performed on column with the same width of the `pl.Array` (for example sum_horizontal could be also defined). In the case of binary array another option is to work with binary string. Any suggestion?

Comment: It may be worth opening an issue about this on github - I can't find anything related to tracking the progress of `pl.Array` support for the various operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explode/implode over a row indicator seems to work. These are copy-free operations btw.

```
(    df
    .with_columns(
        any=(pl.any_horizontal(pl.col("a").explode(), pl.col("b").explode())
                    .implode()
                    .over(pl.int_range(0,pl.count()))
            ).cast(pl.Array(width=2, inner=pl.Boolean))
        )
    )

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ a              ┆ b              ┆ any            │
│ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            │
│ array[bool, 2] ┆ array[bool, 2] ┆ array[bool, 2] │
╞════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ [false, false] ┆ [true, false]  ┆ [true, false]  │
│ [false, true]  ┆ [true, true]   ┆ [true, true]   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert the `any` column from `list[bool]` to `array[bool, 2]` ?

Comment: See edit for array in return.